# How to click a button where the class is the same for another options?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to `click` a *button* from a list but this button has the same class than others in the list because they have the same name `(btn ban-red)` so how can I click it if in the inspect I have this information:

```
<a class=“btn ban-red” data-track-event=“navigate” data-track=name=“Jobylon” - Quality Engineer” href=“https://emp.jobylon.com/jobs/16654-f/” target=“_blank”>View job/a>
```

The inspect is copying this xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/article[14]/a
```

But it is not working

I also created my own xpath this way:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-track-name=‘Jobylon - Quality Engineer’]"))).click();
```

But is not working either

I am using Selenium with java and I am in a Macbook, thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try using `FireBug` and `FirePath` to get right `XPath`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to click a web element at a different index, rather than the first.

As long as you know what index you want to click, you can easily put it in your xpath expression.

By.xpath("(//a[@data-track-name=‘Jobylon - Quality Engineer’])[1]")
By.xpath("(//a[@data-track-name=‘Jobylon - Quality Engineer’])[2]")
By.xpath("(//a[@data-track-name=‘Jobylon - Quality Engineer’])[3]")
etc

Answer (score 0):

Absolute xpath not recommended. You can try using relative xpath.

- Locate based on element text

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'View job')]")).click()
  ```
- Locate using combination of element attribute if classes are not unique

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn ban-red'][@data-track-event='navigate']")).click()
  ```

  **OR**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class="btn ban-red"][@href='https://emp.jobylon.com/jobs/16654-f/']")).click()
  ```

Better to use CSS selector as its faster then xpath. So you try like

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='btn ban-red'][data-track-event='navigate']")).click()
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class="btn ban-red"][href='https://emp.jobylon.com/jobs/16654-f/']")).click()
```

Still facing some issue like element not visible or no such element then try with explicit wait conditions until your element gets visible or clickable.